# Colliding Shapes and making them bounce away from one another

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was starting to teach myself how to work with HTML5 Canvas and decided to learn by making a short game/demo.

I wanted to make a simple blocks bounce around the screen, bounce off the walls, and bounce off each other.

I'm stuck on getting them to bounce off each other. It seems like code that makes it bounce away is making it bounce back immediately after. I see where the code fails but I don't know how to fix it :( Can anyone help?

(Side question: I know I'm not working as clean/efficiently/professionally as possible in this example but if I wanted to improve with feedback and opinions about the 'best' method for this type of example, like a code review or something, is it ok to ask a question on stackoverflow?)

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vdcSv/

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" Width="400" Height="300"></canvas>
```

Javscript:

```
    function CheckBallCollision(BallsArray, index) {
        for (var i = 0; i < BallsArray.length; i++) {
            if (index != i) {
                if (BallsArray[index].Xdir == 1) {
                    if ((BallsArray[index].Xmax >= BallsArray[i].Xmin)) {
                        if ((BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymin) && (BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymin) ||
                       ((BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymax) && (BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymax))) {
                            BallsArray[index].Xdir = -BallsArray[index].Xdir;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (BallsArray[index].Xdir == -1) {
                    if ((BallsArray[index].Xmin <= BallsArray[i].Xmax)) {
                        if ((BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymin) && (BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymin) ||
                       ((BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymax) && (BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymax))) {
                            BallsArray[index].Xdir = -BallsArray[index].Xdir;
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Ball Object:

```
function Ball() {
    this.Xmin = 0;//top left X coord
    this.Ymin = 0;//top left y coord
    this.Height = 25; 
    this.Width = 25;
    this.Xmax = this.Xmin + this.Width;
    this.Ymax = this.Ymin + this.Height;
    this.Xdir = 0; // 0 not moving, 1 moving right, -1 moving left
    this.Ydir = 0;
    this.Red = 0;
    this.Green = 0;
    this.Blue = 200;
    this.Opacity = 1;
    this.Speed = 1;
}
```

Comment: What about the Y-axis direction?

Comment: I'll worry about that later :P First I just want to get it working in one dimension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by changing the <= to ==

It's messy and things often miss the necessary bounce off a block :( I'm sure part of the reason is falling back on the == instead of <=. If anyone has a better solution - I'm all ears :)

http://jsfiddle.net/vdcSv/1/

```
function CheckBallCollision(BallsArray, index) {
        for (var i = 0; i < BallsArray.length; i++) {
            if (index != i) {
                if (BallsArray[index].Xdir == 1) {
                    if ((BallsArray[index].Xmax == BallsArray[i].Xmin)) {
                        if ((BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymin) && (BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymin) ||
                       ((BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymax) && (BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymax))) {
                            BallsArray[index].Xdir = -BallsArray[index].Xdir;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (BallsArray[index].Xdir == -1) {
                    if ((BallsArray[index].Xmin == BallsArray[i].Xmax)) {
                        if ((BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymin) && (BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymin) ||
                       ((BallsArray[index].Ymax >= BallsArray[i].Ymax) && (BallsArray[index].Ymin <= BallsArray[i].Ymax))) {
                            BallsArray[index].Xdir = -BallsArray[index].Xdir;
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple hit detection snippets you might want to look into:

```
ball.hitTestCircle = function(obj) {
    var dx = this.x - obj.x;
    var dy = this.y - obj.y;
    var distance = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);

    var area = (this.radius + obj.radius)*(this.radius + obj.radius);
    return (area / distance);
};
```

if the call returns 1 or greater your colliding, and you can even use that info to fix the difference.

Here is basic rect hit detections script:

```
ball.hitTestRect = function(b) {
    var difference = {};
    difference.x = this.x - b.x - b.width;
    difference.y = this.y - b.y - b.height;
    difference.height = this.height + b.height;
    difference.width = this.width + b.width;

    if (difference.x < 0 && difference.y <= 0 && difference.height + difference.y >= 0 && difference.width + difference.x >= 0) return true;
    return false;
};
```

I would call either of these with something like :

```
for(var i=0;i!=balls.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j!=balls.length;j++){
       if(j!=i){
           if(balls[i].hitTestRect(balls[j])){
               // all your reversing motion code
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to check if

```
BallsArray[index].Xmin <= BallsArray[i].Xmax)
```

If you add this in it works.  It's also worth noting that you don't need different code for the two different X directions as this behaviour is symmetrical.  Regardless of which way it is travelling to begin with you have it reversing direction.  It's also symmetrical in the Y direction so if you just add:

```
BallsArray[index].Ydir = -BallsArray[index].Ydir;
```

to the 'then' part of the `if` you'll only need one if to take care of all four kinds of collisions.

You may also want to add a `break` statement so that if a ball happens to collide with two other balls at the same time it will only reverse direction once.

For a more realistic simulation you can multiply by a negative number in the (0, 1) interval, however if you don't do something else your system will slowly settle into a steady state until the rounding errors kick in and it freaks out.